# Background of tk.Frame() is covered by tk.Label() background

Tags: python, tkinter

### Original Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

home_frame = tk.Frame(win)
home_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
home_frame.config(bg = 'blue', relief = 'raised')

logo = tk.Label(home_frame)
logo.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
logo.config(text = 'Widget', font = ('Helvetica', 30), fg = 'red')

win.config(bg ='white') 
win.mainloop()
```

Note that:

```
home_frame.config(bg = 'blue', relief = 'raised')
```

From this, I would expect the background of the frame to turn blue, yet it doesn't. It remains grey.

### Output:

[image: output]

As far as I'm concerned, `tk.Frame()` does have `bg` as an option.

### Explanation:

If we do the following changes to `logo` background, we get the following:

[image: output2]

Code:

```
logo.config(text = 'Widget', font = ('Helvetica', 30), bg = 'green', fg = 'red')
```

Also, adding another widget, like an `entry` widget, to `home_frame` will yield this:

[image: output3]

Code:

```
search = tk.Entry(home_frame)
search.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
```

From the above, we can tell `logo` covers `home_frame` background.

### Question:

How would you make `logo` background **not cover** `home_frame` background when `logo` background is not defined?

By this I mean:

```
logo.config(text = 'Widget', font = ('Helvetica', 30), fg = 'red') #No background option included.
```

[image: output4]

In this case, I set `logo` background to blue. I want no `bg` option included in `logo.config()`. But still display an output as above.

Comment: If you add `bg='green'` to your `logo.config` line, I think the issue will become apparent.  A tk.Label does not have a transparent background.

Comment: Thank you for the remark, but how would make it transparent? I've tried setting `bg` to `None`. Seems that, by defualt, its grey too. Unlike `win`, you are able to set it to a different `bg`.

Comment: You are supposed to be able to say `win.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','grey')` to declare that grey should always be transparent, but that doesn't work on my Mac, so I didn't add it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make the `home_frame` background invisible.  It just covers up the region it occupies.

Comment: Please let me know If my post is clear.

Comment: It's fine.  Your fundamental question is, "how do I make a tkInter Label widget have a transparent background?"  You might dig into Google for other possibilities.

Comment: If that is your question, it is not possible, you will have to use `canvas.create_image()`, which supports RGBA.